# WDK : get processId by name.exe

Tags: c, windows, process, kernel, driver

I'm developing a driver in Windows Filtering Platform and I need the process ID of another process to do what I need to do. I know only the file name of that process (name.exe).

In win32 I could use the function CreateToolhelp32Snapshot to get the list of all processes and I could search the PID there. ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684834(VS.85).aspx )

Unfortunately in kernel mode this stuff is not available. Anyone know how can I obtain the processID knowing only the binary name, by kernel space?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the timing, it seems that you could call `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx()` with your own handler for `CreateProcessNotifyEx()`.  Your `CreateProcessNotifyEx()` will then receive a pointer to a `PS_CREATE_NOTIFY_INFO`.  In this struct is the field `ImageFileName` and also the bit `FileOpenNameAvailable`.

The program name will be in the Unicode string pointed to by `ImageFileName`.  If `FileOpenNameAvailable`, then that string will contain the fully-qualified path to the binary.  Otherwise, expect to find only the module name, possibly without the extension.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

According with MSDN: "The PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx routine registers or removes a callback routine that notifies the caller when a process is created or exits."


So unfortunately it doesn't seem what I need.
I need to know the process that already are running because my driver are loaded after the application starts.

Comment: @Marco, you are welcome.  Yes, that is what I wondered with "depending on the timing..."  Sorry that doesn't work for you...

If I remember right, the PEB has a double-linked list in it somewhere, and from that you can get to all the PEBs on the system.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the method of taking a process snapshot, traversing the process and comparing the process name to directly obtain the process.

```
DWORD GetProcessIDByName(LPCTSTR szProcessName)
{
    STARTUPINFO st;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    PROCESSENTRY32 ps;
    HANDLE hSnapshot;
    DWORD dwPID = 0;
    ZeroMemory(&st, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    st.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    ZeroMemory(&ps, sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32));
    ps.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return dwPID;
    }
    if (!Process32First(hSnapshot, &ps))
    {
        return dwPID;
    }
    do
    {
        if (lstrcmpi(ps.szExeFile, szProcessName) == 0)     {
            dwPID = ps.th32ProcessID;
        }
    } while (Process32Next(hSnapshot, &ps));
     
    CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
    return dwPID;
}
```

Then get the following code into the main program：

```
DWORD pId = GetProcessIDByName("xxx.exe");
```